# Webpack - unable to set global variables unless set as 'process.env'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm running a React app with Webpack version 3.6.0, and I'm having trouble using the `DefinePlugin` to set global variables - values that are set 'normally', as per the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) are not available throughout the app... however, if I wrap values in an object named `process.env`, the variables are available throughout the app, albeit with the prefix `process.env`.

For example, here is what I'd like my `DefinePlugin` to look like:

```
plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "NODE_ENV": process.env.NODE_ENV ? JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) : JSON.stringify("development"),
        "SIGNUP_PATH": JSON.stringify("signup")
    })
]
```

This does not work - trying to `console.log(NODE_ENV)` or `console.log(SIGNUP_PATH)` does nothing, the variables are `undefined`.

Surprisingly (or maybe not, maybe there's just something I don't know), this works:

```
plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
            "NODE_ENV": process.env.NODE_ENV ? JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) : JSON.stringify("development"),
            "SIGNUP_PATH": JSON.stringify("signup")
        }
    })
]
```

and I can access the variables with `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` and `console.log(process.env.SIGNUP_PATH)`, etc.

Why is it that I have to put everything into an object called `process.env` in order to access it as I would a global?  Am I doing something wrong here, or is there just something that I don't understand about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this problem was due to the fact that I built my app to make use of server-side rendering - it needs two separate Webpack configs, but initially I was only including the `DefinePlugin` settings on the client. Basically, I put everything for the `DefinePlugin` into a separate file, imported it into both the client and server configs, and then bundled it into a final `webpack.config.prod.js` for production (or a similar `webpack.config.dev.js` for development... only production shown below).  Here's how it all came together:

`webpack_config.define-plugin-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "API_URL": process.env.API_URL ? JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL) : JSON.stringify("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/"),
    "SOME_OTHER_VAR": JSON.stringify("foo")
}
```

`webpack.config.server.js`:

```
const Webpack = require("webpack"),
    path = require("path"),
    definePluginConfig = require("./webpack_config/define-plugin-config"),
    rule_js = require("./webpack_config/rule"),
    resolve = require("./webpack_config/resolve")

module.exports = {
    "entry": {
        "component": path.join(__dirname, "js/containers/index.jsx")
    },
    "output": {
        "path": path.join(__dirname, "../priv/static/server/js"),
        "filename": "app.js",
        "library": "dl",
        "libraryTarget": "commonjs2"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            rule_js
        ]
    },
    "resolve": resolve,
    "plugins": [
        new Webpack.DefinePlugin(definePluginConfig)
    ]
}
```

`webpack.config.client.js`:

```
const Webpack = require("webpack"),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),
    path = require("path"),
    definePluginConfig = require("./webpack_config/define-plugin-config"),
    rule_js = require("./webpack_config/rule"),
    resolve = require("./webpack_config/resolve")

module.exports = {
    "entry": [
        path.join(__dirname, "js/index.jsx"),
        path.join(__dirname, "styles/index.scss")
    ],
    "output": {
        "path": path.join(__dirname, "../priv/static"),
        "filename": "js/app.js",
        "publicPath": "/"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            rule_js,
            {
                "test": /\.scss$/,
                "use": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    "fallback": "style-loader",
                    "use": ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                })
            },
            {
                "test": /\.css$/,
                "use": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    "fallback": "style-loader",
                    "use": ["css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]"]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    "resolve": resolve,
    "plugins": [
        new Webpack.DefinePlugin(definePluginConfig),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            "filename": "css/app.css",
            "allChunks": true
        }),
        new CopyPlugin([{ "from": path.join(__dirname, "static") }])
    ]
}
```

`webpack.config.prod.js`:

```
const clientWebPackConfig = require("./webpack.config.client"),
    serverWebPackConfig = require("./webpack.config.server"),
    UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin"),
    webpackConfig = [clientWebPackConfig, serverWebPackConfig],
    uglifyJsPluginOptions = { "sourceMap": true }

webpackConfig[0].plugins = [...webpackConfig[0].plugins, new UglifyJsPlugin(uglifyJsPluginOptions)]

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. Anywhere In my code I can reference __ API_URL __

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `${__dirname}/src/.dev.env` });
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const { DefinePlugin, EnvironmentPlugin } = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let plugins = [
  new EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),
  new ExtractPlugin('bundle-[hash].css'),
  new HtmlPlugin({ template: `${__dirname}/src/index.html` }),
  new DefinePlugin({
    __DEBUG__: JSON.stringify(!production),
    __API_URL__: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
    __GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID__: JSON.stringify(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
    __AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID__: JSON.stringify(process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID),
    __AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY__: JSON.stringify(process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
  }),
];
```

Comment: This is good advice, but it didn't specifically solve my problem. I realized that the issue was that my app is set up to use server-side rendering and uses two separate Webpack configurations, the variables needed to be declared in both places in order to behave correctly... otherwise, they always needed the `process.env.` prefix.

Comment: @skwidbreth Could you possibly add an answer demonstrating your solution? I think it would help a lot of people having the same issue.

Comment: @silkfire my apologies, I had totally forgotten about this. I've posted my solution, let me know if you have any other trouble.

Answer (score 0):

leave out the quotes. "NODE_ENV" should be NODE_ENV

Comment: I tested that - same problem :(

Comment: this looks correct to me, I think the issue is somewhere else in your code. are you using a dotenv and a .env file for your environment variables?